# change values of a rangevalidator based on current date

Tags: asp.net, validation

I have a asp:rangevalidator control on a textbox that is used to enter the birthdate.

```
<asp:RangeValidator ID="valrDate" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtDateOfBirth" MinimumValue="12/31/1950" MaximumValue="1/1/2012" Type="Date" text="Invalid Date" Display="Dynamic"/>
```

I would really like the ability to change the values of the minimum and maximum based on logic that will throw up a validation notice that indicates the date entered is outside of the allowed range of dates.

Can this be accomplished?

thanks
tony

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can set it in code behind like:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    datetime dynamicMaxValue;
    datetime dynamicMinValue;

    //Code to compute dynamic Max/Min Value
    //...
    valrDate.MaximumValue = dynamicMaxValue; //Dynamic Max Value
    valrDate.MinimumValue = dynamicMinValue; //Dynamic Min Value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void RangeValidator5_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ((RangeValidator)sender).MaximumValue = DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
    ((RangeValidator)sender).MinimumValue = DateTime.Today.AddYears(-100).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
}
```